# Insert a row in a table based on a value of another row with user input

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to find a way to insert a row in a table based on a value that the user inputs and if that value exists in the table. For example, the table will have 10 rows. The user would like to add a row beneath row number 8. [Please see screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMD12.png)

```html
<form>
  <table class="myTable" id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th class="myTable th">PALLET #</th>
      <th class="myTable th">CASE COUNT</th>
      <th class="myTable th">HILLTOP LOT #</th>
      <th class="myTable th">SSCC (LAST 4)</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
      for ($x=1 ; $x <=2 4; $x++) { 
      echo 
        '<tr>
         <td style="font-size: 160%" id="pallet">' .$x. '</td>
         <td id="caseCount"><input type="text" id="inputText_Small" name="caseCount" value="" maxlength="2"/></td>
         <td id="hilltopLot"><input type="text" id="inputText_Order" name="hilltopLot" value="" maxlength="10"/></td>
         <td id="sscc"><input type="text" id="inputText_Medd" name="sscc" value="" maxlength="4"/></td>
         </tr>'; 
    } 
   ?>
  </table>
```

After clicking on the "Add Line" button and typing 8, it will look for row number 8 and insert a row beneath it also naming it row 8.

```html
  <br />
  <br />
  <p class="center">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="blueButt_Big" />&nbsp&nbsp
    <input class="blueButt_Big" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="parent.location='view_prodLine.php'" />&nbsp&nbsp
    <input class="blueButt_Big" type="button" value="Add Line" onclick="addLine()" />&nbsp&nbsp
    <input class="blueButt_Big" type="button" value="Delete Line" onclick="myDeleteFunction()" />
</form>
<script>
  function addLine() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter the pallet number");
    if (person != null) {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      cell1.innerHTML = person;
      cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="inputText_Small" name="caseCount" value="" maxlength="2"/>';
      cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="inputText_Order" name="hilltopLot" value="" maxlength="10"/>';
      cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="inputText_Medd" name="sscc" value="" maxlength="4"/>';
```

I've only been able to add a row to the very bottom of the table after prompting the user for input. I know I can specify where the row is inserted using the code I commented out. The obvious problem is that the position where it will insert the new row will change if the user adds more than one line. I fear I may be overthinking it, any thoughts?

```html
      //var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[22].cells;
      //x[0].innerHTML = person;
    }
  }

  function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Look at my new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p01r7sjb/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3 cell1</td>
    <td>Row3 cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<input type="number" id="RowNumber"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

    var RowNumber = document.getElementById("RowNumber").value;

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(RowNumber);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
</script>
```

See it working here:
https://jsfiddle.net/p01r7sjb/1/

Comment: Thank you Anokrize. This works somewhat to what I had in mind, however it still adds rows based solely on user input. I would like for the user to enter "3" and add a row below the 3rd row, regardless of where it may be positioned. Your solution adds a row after the 3rd position and not the row labeled Row 3. For example if I entered 1, it would add "New Cell" after row 1 and then if I entered 2 it would add a row after the "New Cell" row and not Row 2.

Comment: Ah you mean that you are giving like an id for every row and if the user enters the id, then it should be inserted after that id? @RickColin

Comment: Correct! Is there a way to give every row an id exactly how you described it? @Anokrize

Comment: This took me quite a bit so please accept it as the answer if that is what you need. If you have any questions, ask me. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I modified it slightly to add the new row under the existing row:                                                                                                                 var newRow = table.insertRow(Position+1);            @Anokrize